# String replace - Attributed string

Tags: ios8, uitextview, nsattributedstring

Here is my HTML response

```
<p><strong>Ezekiel 33:1-20&nbsp;<br /><br /></strong>
<strong><sup>1</sup></strong> The word of the&nbsp;Lord&nbsp;came to me:&nbsp;<strong><sup>2&nbsp;</sup></strong>
&ldquo;Son of man, speak to your people and tell them: Suppose I bring the sword against a land, and the people of that land select a man from among them, appointing him as their watchman,&nbsp;
<strong><sup>3&nbsp;</sup></strong>
```

I want to display the above HTMLs in UITextView as an attributed string with the condition `<strong>` to `</strong>` as red color ,Here my code.

```
attributedString2 = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",readingPartCntnt] 
dataUsingEncoding:NSUnicodeStringEncoding] options:@{ NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType } 
   documentAttributes:nil error:nil];
    NSRange rang = [readingPartCntnt rangeOfString:@"<strong>" options:NSBackwardsSearch];
if (rang.location == NSNotFound) {
    NSLog(@"string was not found");
} else {
    NSLog(@"position %lu", (unsigned long)rang.location);
}
NSRange rang1 = [readingPartCntnt rangeOfString:@"</strong>" options:NSBackwardsSearch];
if (rang1.location == NSNotFound) {
    NSLog(@"string was not found");
} else {
    NSLog(@"position %lu", (unsigned long)rang1.location);
}

[attributedString2 addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor redColor] range:rang];
[attributedString2 addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor redColor] range:rang1];
```

Its not applying properly.Please help me to resolve.

Comment: I'd suggest to replace the strong tag with the red colored one in the original string, the using the NSAttritedString method to read it.

Answer (score 0):

The following code did it for me:

```
readingPartCntnt = [readingPartCntnt stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"<strong>" withString:@"<strong style=\"color: red;\">"];

attributedString2 = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",readingPartCntnt] 
    dataUsingEncoding:NSUnicodeStringEncoding] options:@{ NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType } 
    documentAttributes:nil error:nil];

self.textView.attributedText = attributedString2.copy;
```

This will change the CSS style of the original string before creating the attributed string.